# SQL data validation

Tags: sql

In SQL how do you validate multiple columns. 
I am working on

```
CREATE TABLE booking(hotelNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo, num_Days, total_charge)

CREATE TABLE room(roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
```

I have 2 questions. How do I check to not book data in the same `(hotelNo, dateFrom, roomNo)`?
And for `total_charge` how to I apply the value of `price` from `room` table to a trigger in `booking` to calculate `total_charge` = `num_days` * `price`?

Thank you so much for any hint.

Comment: My first thought was to use an index, but that won't work here: you need to prevent booking `hotelNo` + `roomNo` with an **overlapping** `dateFrom, dateTo` date range. The only way that comes to mind is to use a stored procedure to update `booking`, and make the table itself inaccessible to normal users. What database are you using?

Comment: Triggers are highly vendor specific. [Edit] the question and add the tag of the DBMS you're using.

Comment: The other thing I see is that storing `total_charge` puts `booking` in an abnormal form (I forget which one) because `total_charge` can _always_ be calculated from `room.price` and `booking.num_Days`.

Comment: Drop the column `hotelno` from `booking`. It's redundant. The `hotelno` can be determined by looking at the `hotelno` in `room` for the given `roomnumber` in `booking`. Also drop `num_days`, it's directly dependent of `datefrom` and `dateto`.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: Hmm, in this case it might actually make sense to materialize the total charge. It's probably wanted to reflect the price at the time the booking was made and shouldn't change when the price for the room changes some time in the future. Only future bookings should have the new price.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: such a constraint is actually possible in Postgres

Comment: @stickybit True. I suppose I'm a bit rusty at this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How would you write that?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: using an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). Here is an example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0018d39ac6e5d31f5985f3e365870997 Btw: num_days is not needed either because that can be calculated from the two date columns.